# Delete some remembered text from Browser TextBox

Tags: macos, safari, auto-complete

in Windows you can put the curser on text box (focus on it) and push down arrow key ( <kbd>down</kbd> ) and the list of all text that textbox was remembered was shown, then you can move on them by up and sown arrow key and if press <kbd>Delete</kbd> on highlighted text it was removed but I can't do the same in my macbook pro. it doesn't have <kbd>Delete</kbd> key and this button act as <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> and it won't act if you press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>  . any one have any idea to delete remembered text in macbook-pro(os x).

[image]   [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> on windows.  In Firefox on my MacBook, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> does the trick.

Don't ask me why I know this.  That comment below Josh K's answer was totally hypothetical.

Comment: In windows I just use delete not shift+delete, and I read your comment under Josh k answer, It's a good reason to learn something special.

Answer (score 0):

Clear form and search history. That's what it's called in Firefox. In Safari remove the Autocomplete setting.

Comment: I think he's actually asking how to remove individual searches or auto-completes from the list.  Like when you search "porn movies" and forgot to turn on private browsing, but don't want your girlfriend to know you searched for that in her browser.  If you remove all history, she'll want to know what you have to hide, but if you leave the search in there, it might pop up when she's searching for potato salad.  The only viable solution is a precision strike, not carpet bombing.

Comment: @calavera: Ah, that's interesting.